# Where can I get user information of which I loged in on Azure hosted app

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-web-app-service

I have simple website hosted on Azure
Site is secured by azure, only logged in user can enter the page
Login in is done by azure, no code on hosted site.

How can I retrieved current user with which I logged in on this page?

edit:

I have this in the request:
Cookie: ARRAffinity=xxxxae0c51eb40xxxx308de2a1xxxx2b35f53f6xxxxe328xxxxba25609xxx; msal.login.request=https://site.azurewebsites.net/msal.html; msal.authority|xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxaxxxxxxx=https://login.microsoftonline.com/company.cloud/; msal.nonce.idtoken=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx; msal.state.login=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx; msal.authority|xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx=https://login.microsoftonline.com/company.cloud/

Comment: Trying to get your Question right, 
Do you mean you created a site that is hosted on Azure and only Logged in users can see a particular page. However you would like to know the current user that Logged in on that particular page ?

Answer (score 1):

Per my understanding, you are using App service easy auth. App Service passes user claims to your application by using special headers. External requests aren't allowed to set these headers, so they are present only if set by App Service. Some example headers include:

- X-MS-CLIENT-PRINCIPAL-NAME
- X-MS-CLIENT-PRINCIPAL-ID

So you can get user information from the request header.

Reference:

[Access user claims](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-how-to#access-user-claims)

Comment: I don't see this headers in the response or the request. But I have this in the request: Cookie: ARRAffinity=xxxxae0c51eb40xxxx308de2a1xxxx2b35f53f6xxxxe328xxxxba25609xxx; msal.login.request=https://site.azurewebsites.net/msal.html; msal.authority|xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxaxxxxxxx=https://login.microsoftonline.com/company.cloud/; msal.nonce.idtoken=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx; msal.state.login=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx; msal.authority|xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx=https://login.microsoftonline.com/company.cloud/

Comment: @Jacek You should get the headers from your code. Just like  `request.headers`, `request.headers.get('X-MS-CLIENT-PRINCIPAL-NAME')`

Comment: "request.headers.get('X-MS-CLIENT-PRINCIPAL-NAME')" -> 

"VM41:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: request is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:1"            
Do I need some library to have request to not be undefined?

Comment: @Jacek Yes, you need to include http lib and it depends on your server code. From your server code, the provider-specific tokens are injected into the request header. For example, if you use `python`, you will need to import request module, then you can get it like this `request.headers['your-header-name']`